# In android studio when running the application. I got this error Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc

Hi I am trying to connect the android application with SQL developer using ojdbc14 jar with java . But when I am running the code I am getting the following error. Here is my and the errors accordingly.

```
/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
W/System.err:     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
        at com.example.software2.bank.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7227)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7218)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
```

1. Below is my java code

```
package com.example.software2.bank;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private static String Classes = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

  private Connection connection = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            Class.forName(Classes);
            DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
            connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcle19", "system", "tiger");

            //DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcle19", "system", "tiger");

            textView.setText("SUCCESS");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textView.setText("ERROR");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textView.setText("FAILURE");
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void sqlButton(View view){
        if (connection!=null){
            Statement statement = null;
            try {
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from student;");
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    textView.setText(resultSet.getString(0));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            textView.setText("Connection is null");
        }
    }
}
```

I have also correctly established the oracle SQL developer connection. This is the screenshot
[Oracle SQL developer connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad9Bl.png)

Comment: Don't connect to the `SYSTEM` user! Create a different user and use that.

Comment: I tried but nothing happened. The error is the same

Comment: That was not an answer; that was general advice that if you use the `SYSTEM` user then you run the risk of changing something critical to the database and making it unusable. In general you should never use the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` (or any other oracle-created) users to connect to the database and should create a user to contain your data.

Comment: then what will I do?

Comment: Wait for someone to give you an answer to your question. While you do that, check your firewall has opened the port and do some debugging yourself.

Comment: How to check firewall has opened the port

Comment: You really shouldn't use a JDBC driver from Android. Instead, create a REST API (e.g. using Spring Boot), to mediate between your application and the database server.